# Return the first item in a list matching a condition

Tags: python

I have a function. `matchCondition(a)`, which takes an integer and either returns True or False.

I have a list of 10 integers. I want to return the first item in the list (in the same order as the original list) that has `matchCondition` returning True.

As pythonically as possible.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
next(x for x in lst if matchCondition(x))
```

should work, but it will raise `StopIteration` if none of the elements in the list match.  You can suppress that by supplying a second argument to `next`:

```
next((x for x in lst if matchCondition(x)), None)
```

which will return `None` if nothing matches.

Demo:

```
>>> next(x for x in range(10) if x == 7)  #This is a silly way to write 7 ...
7
>>> next(x for x in range(10) if x == 11)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> next((x for x in range(10) if x == 7), None)
7
>>> print next((x for x in range(10) if x == 11), None)
None
```

---

Finally, just for completeness, if you want *all* the items that match in the list, that is what the builtin `filter` function is for:

```
all_matching = filter(matchCondition,lst)
```

In python2.x, this returns a list, but in python3.x, it returns an iterable object.

Comment: Interesting application of `next`, I never would have thought of it.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- It's an idiom that I picked up around here once upon a time and for whatever reason I've never let it go.  As a side note, the performance of generator expressions i've found to be pretty poor.  For small lists you don't gain any benefit from the short circuiting...i.e. `[x for x in lst if matchCondition(x)][0]` is *probably* faster in a lot of applications (or the corresponding expression using `filter`, but that's not python2 python3 compatible ...

Comment: But to make it safe in the case of no matching results you would need `([x for x in lst if matchCondition(x)] or [None])[0]` which is really ugly.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- Never even thought of doing it that way, but I agree -- That's not the way to go and performance isn't everything (hence my answer).  I just figured that it should be documented *somewhere* that this isn't always the best performing variation of this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `break` statement:

```
for x in lis:
  if matchCondition(x):
     print x
     break            #condition met now break out of the loop
```

now `x` contains the item you wanted.

**proof:**

```
>>> for x in xrange(10):
   ....:     if x==5:
   ....:         break
   ....:         

>>> x
>>> 5
```

Comment: This is fine unless none of the conditions match then it just returns `collection[-1]`

Comment: @JakobBowyer to handle that we have the for-else` loop.